# Find limit of function with argument

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a^x-1}{x}\right)$
I replace ${a^x-1} = t$ but dont know, what doing next.

Comment: Apply L'Hospital immediatly.

Comment: need without this rule.

Comment: @Cornman How do you take the derivative of $a^x$?

Comment: @DmitrySokolov How do you define $a^x$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: $a^x=e^{\ln(a)x}$

Comment: @Cornman Yes, and how do you take the derivative of $e^{\ln(a)x}$? The point is that the derivative is *defined to be* the limit in question, so L'Hospital's sends us straight to the original problem.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I did not think about that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of the derivative of the function $y \mapsto a^y$ at $y=0$. Equivalently, $y \mapsto \exp(y \log(a))$, which you can differentiate using the chain rule.